# vim xterm-kitty problem

Tags: vimrc, kitty-terminal

Using Vim with Kitty , the client area redraw doesn't work when I resize the window; in this context `set term` returns `term=xterm-kitty`.

However, starting Vim with `vim -T kitty` the redrawing of the resized window works correctly (in this context `set term` returns `term=kitty`).

However, the `set term kitty` configuration in vimrc is rejected as an unknown option (E518).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should do:

```
set term=kitty
```

Comment: Of course; sorry for the silly question!
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Vim! You are welcome. If the solution address your problem you can accept it using the v green button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)